# Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS Installation step failed

Tags: 16.04, server

I got the message "Installation step failed an installation step failed. you can try to run the failing item again from the menu, or skip it and choose something else. The failing step is: select and install software".I tried burning different USB Sticks, redownload the iso file, double checking disk partitioning, everything!!! None of them works! (Installing Ubuntu Desktop works fine but Ubuntu Server just keeps failing)

Comment: I did tons of research, basically tried every solution I found on the internet and none of them works! Is there any way around this?(like install ubuntu desktop first and  then convert? Something like that?)

Comment: did you use a USB image or a CD image? does the installer have internet access?

Comment: I downloaded the iso and then used UltraISO, burned it to usb stick (bootable). The installer does have internet access during installation. Everything works fine until that step.

Comment: My first guess is that you burned a CD image so it is looking for the repo on a CD instead of the USB.

Comment: Okay how can I solve this? There are only ISO files to download...

Comment: is it possible to get internet access?

Comment: Yes, it does have internet access. What do I need to do?

Comment: when you install, select "get updates onliine" it should allow you to select an online repo to install from.

Comment: I do not know what you re talking about, there is no such step or option. There is one with automatically install updates, but it does not affect anything, still installation step failed.

Comment: Which one is the step that failes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved. Not sure what exactly solved it but, this is what I did:

1. I bought a new USB (16 GB)
2. I Used `Universal USB Installer` instead of `UltraISO` (I think this was most likely the problem)
3. I Made the boot partition 5 GB larger

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I just had the same issue installing server 14.04.

I was manually creating the partitions:

- 10GB /
- 350GB Home
- 4GB Swap

I tried to use a different ISO (plus Rufus) and had the same problem.

Problem disappeared when I used guided partitioning: whole drive and separate home which gave me the same configuration as above.

Then installed fine.